# Looking for paper: "Simulation and calibration of the HJM model" by Andersen

Tags: reference-request

I've Googled for the paper and found [this site](http://citeseer.uark.edu:8080/citeseerx/showciting;jsessionid=07D3B5EBCF02C0639A76CFC02D937474?cid=8287542&sort=date) but it's down (at the moment).

Note, this is not a quest for a free copy (or we wouldn't allow it :), the paper is also nowhere to find *for* a fee. A guy on [Wilmott](http://www.pauldominic.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=91287) was also looking for it but it seems without success. It is cited in Paul Glasserman's book "Monte Carlo simulation methods in financial engineering".

Comment: please edit the question explaining what do you need and citing the paper you're looking for.

Comment: The link you found doesn't give much, at least not if I look in the Google Cache.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the working paper, the [SSRN page](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/cf_dev/AbsByAuth.cfm?per_id=111031#reg) doesn't give any papers from before 1998 which happens to be the year of the Glasserman publication(?). However, [this paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=946405) I found could be based on the working paper.